# Is there a size limit to upload file using webapp2?

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

I am using appengine and writing my server code in python using webapp2. I am trying to upload video files from browser and save it to Google cloud storage. I use the form element in my HTML and webapp2 handler on server side to upload the file from browser. It works for files of smaller size, but when I try to upload a video file greater than 100MB, the browser throws the blow error

This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

I am unable to debug this on server side as it doesn't hit the post method.
Is there a config parameter in web app 2 that can be modified to upload files of greater size?

Any inputs is greatly appreciated.

Comment: webapp2 is innocent -- as Andrei Volgin mentions, the 32MB limit is intrinsic to App Engine, whatever framework you choose to use on top of it. Use GCS, e.g via signed URLs per https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control?hl=en#Signed-URLs , and live happily ever after!-)

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the input, I actually tried using the blob store api to upload to GCS and it worked. So, Signed URL also does the same thing?  or is it just used to server the objects in GCS.

Comment: Signed URLs allow downloads, uploads, deletions (up to an expiration time you can specify) -- they're a very flexible tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App Engine has a limit of 32MB on all requests. You should upload your files directly to Google Cloud Storage, not through your server. This will also save you a lot of instance time.

EDIT: As Alex mentioned, [signed URLs](http://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control?hl=en#Signed-URLs) is a great way to let users upload and download files directly from GCS.

Comment: Yep, exactly. I also commented on the original Q giving the signed-urls reference -- I think you want to edit your A to add that though I'm upvoting it anyway!-)